# Display query in view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

lets say the query from my controller is $query.
how to display the data other than using this kind of code?

```
foreach($query as $row){
echo $row->student_id;
}
```

any other than this coz the query only have one row
any way that can i access the returned array like this?

```
$query['student_id'];
```

Comment: Another alternative is to store the data in a session which can be accessed anywhere on your site without querying every time. Some data ideal for storing in a session is a usernames or user id. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say your table have the following fields

```
student_id and student_name
```

have your model or controller return only one row.

```
function get_first_student() {

    $query = this->db->select('*')->from('student')-where('student_id','1')->limit(1);
    $data['stuff'] =  $query->row_array(); // or $query->row() which returns an object
    $this->load->view('whatever',$data)

}
```

then in your view

```
<p>student name: <?= $stuff['student_name'] ?> </p>
<p>student id: <?= $stuff['student_id'] ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `$query->row()` just fetches the first row.

So instead of looping through the result, you could just do:

```
$student_id = $query->row()->student_id; // (untested)
```

OR

```
$row = $query->row();
$student_id = $row->student_id;
```

Assuming the query will always return a row.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are displaying a user's profile. It's good practice to store all database queries in the MODEL. I use this:

CONTROLLER:

```
$this->load->model('Profile');
$data['row'] = $this->Profile_model->profile_read(); //get profile data
$this->load->view('profile_view', $data); //load data to view
```

MODEL:

```
function profile_read()
{
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles'); //get all data from user_profiles table that belong to the respective user
        return $query->row(); //return the data    
}
```

In the model you can have all your other database functions (create, delete, update)

VIEW:

```
<?php echo $row->name; ?>
<?php echo $row->email; ?>
<?php echo $row->about; ?>
etc
```

Finally in the view you can echo any rows from the table that belong to the user.